# Select billing and update price on real time without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to create a cart page. There are many products which require you to select billing cycle like monthly, semi-annually, annually with the help of select dropdown. When we select the billing cycle of the product, it automatically updates the price displayed on the page without a refresh.

Let's say I am fetching the product price from a PHP array using this.

```
$price['monthly'];
$price['quarterly'];
$price['semi-annually'];
$price['annually'];
```

Now when I get value from the dropdown, I store it in `$billing` so to store it as billing cycle like monthly, quarterly, semi-annually, etc. Then I use js to submit the select option as soon as they select a dropdown and the selected value of dropdown comes in `$billing`.

I use: `echo $price['$billing'];` to show the price of the product. But all of this happens with a refresh of the page.

I have given the code of what I am doing below:

Here, `$price` is the array containing product price, `$symbol` is the currency code, `$currency` is the currency. In the end, I have displayed the link and updated the displayed price.

I am trying to display the price of the product according to the billing and update the link on a page without a refresh. I am also facing an issue that if I use multiple dropdowns for the same thing on my webpage. Then only the first dropdown works and the other two don't work even after refresh. I have written this code from inspiration from many places, I might be wrong and there might be an easier way to implement this. I am looking to optimize it. Please help

Is it possible? If yes then how?

**PHP**:

```
 <?php
    // Set Billing variable
    if(isset($_GET['billing']) && !empty($_GET['billing']))
    {
     $_SESSION['billing'] = $_GET['billing'];

     if(isset($_SESSION['billing']) && $_SESSION['billing'] != $_GET['billing'])
     {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'> location.reload(); </script>";
     }
    }
    // Include Billing file
    if(isset($_SESSION['billing'])){
     $billing= $_SESSION['billing'];
    }else{
     $billing='monthly';
    }

    $currency='USD';
    $symbol='$';
    ?>
    <!--Change Billing Cycle--> 
      <script>
     function changeBilling(){
      document.getElementById('form_billing').submit();
     }
     </script>
```

**HTML**:

```
 <form method='get' action='' id='form_billing' >
       <select name='billing' onchange='changeBilling();'>
       <option value='monthly' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['billing']) && $_SESSION['billing'] == 'monthly'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
           <?php echo $symbol; echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $price['monthly']), 2 ); echo " "; echo $currency;?> Monthly
           </option>
       <option value='quarterly' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['billing']) && $_SESSION['billing'] == 'quarterly'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
           <?php echo $symbol; echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $price['quarterly']), 2 ); echo " "; echo $currency;?> Quarterly
           </option>
       <option value='semiannually' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['billing']) && $_SESSION['billing'] == 'semiannually'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
           <?php echo $symbol; echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $price['semiannually']), 2 ); echo " "; echo $currency;?> Semi-Annually
           </option>
       <option value='annually' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['billing']) && $_SESSION['billing'] == 'annually'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
           <?php echo $symbol; echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $price['annually']), 2 ); echo " "; echo $currency;?> Annually
           </option>
       <option value='biennially' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['billing']) && $_SESSION['billing'] == 'biennially'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
           <?php echo $symbol; echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $price['biennially']), 2 ); echo " "; echo $currency;?> Biennially
           </option>
       <option value='triennially' <?php if(isset($_SESSION['billing']) && $_SESSION['billing'] == 'triennially'){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
           <?php echo $symbol; echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $price['triennially']), 2 ); echo " "; echo $currency;?> Triennially
           </option>
      </select>
     </form>

<?phpecho $price[$billing];
echo '<br>';
?>
<a href="<?php echo 'https://example.com/index.php?currency=';echo $currency; echo '&billingcycle=';echo $billing; ?>Click here to purchase</a>
```

An example image of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to make the billing cycle update without having to refresh the page? Is that the gist of it?

Comment: Yes. I want to use it to update price on website without refresh.

Comment: How can it be implemented in my code??

Comment: Typically you use an AJAX call, from JavaScript, to do what you are asking. I suggest you look into what AJAX is, what it does, how to use it, etc. jQuery has a syntax for firing off AJAX calls, for example.